# Copying files from SitePages in SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, open-with-explorer, sitepages

I am trying copy a large number of files from the SitePages library on one SharePoint 2013 Online subsite to another, but am unable to find a sensibly quick way of doing this.

On SharePoint 2010 I would usually access the files using the "**Open in Explorer**" link (bypassing the lack of this option by opening Explorer from another document library and then navigating to SitePages within Explorer), however this option is not working for me for any SP2013 libraries - I receive the error:

> We're having trouble opening this library in File Explorer. Syncing
>   this library will give you better experience.

...as described on the Microsoft Support page ["How to use the "Open with Explorer" command and how to troubleshoot issues with this option in SharePoint Online"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2629108) and I seem to be unable to fix the problem using any of these suggested fixes:

- "Authenticate to Office 365": I have ensured login details are stored in both Internet Explorer and SharePoint Designer, but still no luck.
- "Add your SharePoint Online sites to trusted sites": Unable to do this as IE security settings are managed by company admin.
- "Check the status of the WebClient service": restarting this seems to have no effect.

**Syncing** using OneDrive for Business as suggested in the error message is an acceptable workaround for other libraries, but the option is not available for SitePages.

**SharePoint Designer** doesn't appear to help me here either - I am only able to use the "Export File" option on a single file, not on folders or when selecting multiple files.

Are there any other possible options for this, or should I resign myself to an afternoon of manually copying files one-by-one?

(I am using IE11 on Windows 7)

Comment: This is a fix/reference to your open with explorer error.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2629108

Comment: @imoses, that link is already mentioned in the post above

Comment: Pardon me, I missed that. As an additional reference, repairing MS Office has worked as a fix for me when supporting SP2010. It may also help with sp2013.

Comment: Are the two sites in the same site collection?

Comment: @imoses Yes, both sites are in the same SiteCollection, but I'd really like to be able to get a local copy of the files for development anyway. I've updated my answer to outline my attempts at fixing the "Open with Explorer" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two sites are in the same collection, use the Site Content and Structure function from site settings (sitemanager.aspx).

You can't use it to move folders, but you can select multiple files within Site pages and use the copy or move function from the dropdown menu (actions > copy).